# how to change header length in esapi properties

Tags: java, owasp, esapi

i am getting below error when i am running my application

```
WARNING: [SECURITY FAILURE Anonymous:null@unknown -> 127.0.0.1:8080/ExampleApplication/SecurityWrapperResponse] Attempt to set invalid header denied
org.owasp.esapi.errors.ValidationException: setHeader: Invalid input. The maximum length of 20 characters was exceeded.
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.validation.StringValidationRule.checkLength(StringValidationRule.java:214)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.validation.StringValidationRule.checkLength(StringValidationRule.java:229)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.validation.StringValidationRule.getValid(StringValidationRule.java:281)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator.getValidInput(DefaultValidator.java:214)
    at org.owasp.esapi.reference.DefaultValidator.getValidInput(DefaultValidator.java:185)
    at org.owasp.esapi.filters.SecurityWrapperResponse.setHeader(SecurityWrapperResponse.java:447)
```

i have tried by changing below property but it did not work

Validator.HTTPHeaderName=^[a-zA-Z0-9\-_]{1,32}$ have changed 32 to 50 but it is still throwing same error

my header is response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); it is working when i comment this line, can you please help me how to change header name length in esapi.properties file

Comment: How are you loading `validator.properties`?  Do you have an entry overriding the one you're using in your `esapi.properties` file?

Comment: Thank you, I have solved the issue, in request wrapper class they are hard coded the length, so i have override the class with new length and it is working

Answer (score 1):

Package contained hard coded length values in SecurityWrapperResponse class, so i have solved the problem by overriding the class and changing the new length.
It is working.